# MongoDB schema design and computation for aggregated data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have an application that stores users and their behavior in the form of events (in two collections). An important feature of the application is to query the users based on behavior and properties, for example: "**All users with property X that did trigger event Y at least 10 times within the last Z days/weeks/months"**.

Until now I've been doing this on the raw data using `aggregate()` on the contact collection with a `$lookup` on events. However as the event collection grows this becomes slow.

My idea is to store some pre-aggregated version of the event data in a separate collection, with one document for every unique event/user combination. These documents would store:

- the total number of times this event was triggered by this user
- the last time he triggered it
- how often he triggered it in some pre-defined time intervals for the last days/weeks/months

The documents in that collection would look like this:

```
{
    event: 'my_event',
    user: '593aaa84c685604066a6a0cf',
    total: 79,
    last: '2016-11-01T04:39:52.667Z',
    days: { 0: 4, 1: 8, 2: 4 ... }, // 7 values here (0=today)
    weeks: { ... }, // 3 values here
    months: { ... } // 12 values here
}
```

However I'm struggling to figure out a good strategy for computing the values for the time intervals and how to keep this data up to date.

**Do you have any suggestions or alternative approaches? Every idea is welcome :)**

Comment: Aggregate is the good way, if its slow, try to add index on the requested match keys mySchema.index({v1:1}); or mySchema.index({v1:1, v2:1, v3: 1});. And have you tried to reverse the lookup ? Query the events then lookup users ?

Comment: Indexes are already in place. The problem isn't only the speed of the query but also the amount of times I need to run it. I didn't mention that the queries are used to calculate segments of users in near-realtime - so every time a user's data changes or he triggers a new event I have to run multiple queries aggregation queries to check if the user matches the filter conditions of certain segments. So anything that makes the queries faster / use less resources is good.

Comment: Or to put the question another way: Wouldn't it have a significant performance advantage to store the pre-computed sums for the different events and time periods instead of fetching all events and aggregate to calculate the numbers on the fly every time?

Comment: In this way its better to store pre-aggregate datas. Tthe better i think it to store an preaggregate collection, but don't update it in real time ; use a cron each X minutes/hours to update the aggregate colleciton